# How to style html <option> tag like google does?

Tags: html, tags, styles

Take a look at [gmail sign up](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail) page and look at the birthday and gender field. Please someone show me how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not style that can make  like this. This is a image+input box, when you click the image, DIV is generated in javascript populating all the entries within it. The similar example would be like [this](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#).